# How to use the "WHERE LIKE" command in SQL

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am trying to use the WHERE LIKE command in my program.

**My Code**

```
String searchCriteria = searchTextField.getText();
String searchCriteria1 ="'"+"%" + searchCriteria + "%"+"'";\
String query = "select ID,Priority,recipient,Sender,Label,Subject from Messages where Message like = '" + searchCriteria1 + "'";
        PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

**Code Explained**

1.What this code codes is get the input from the user.

2.Creates a string variable that contains the search condition and the "%" either side of the condition.

3.The last few lines execute the SQL query.

I am currently getting the error `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "=" at line 1, column 92.` and not sure whats wrong with my statement.

Its most likely to be something very silly and small, I hope you can help.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is something silly and small. Hint: print out `query` before the `prepareStatement` call.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you have single quotes twice over in the search criteria.

But you need to use prepared statement with bind parameters in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PreparedStatement like this:

```
String searchCriteria = searchTextField.getText();
String query = "select ID,Priority,recipient,Sender,Label,Subject from Messages where Message like ?";
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setString(1, "%" + searchCriteria + "%");
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your `modulus(%)` in your variable you can put it at the query itself and remove your `equal(=)` symbol. See below:

```
String searchCriteria1 =" + searchCriteria + ";
String query = "SELECT ID,Priority,recipient,Sender,Label,Subject FROM Messages WHERE Message LIKE '%" + searchCriteria1 + "%'";
```